# Symfony2, Doctrine search and order by distance

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, distance

I have a database of places which I store the latitude and longitude for. I want to query the database to find all places within a radius (`$requestedDistance`) of a specific latitude (`$latitude`) and longitude (`$longitude`).

The below query works and returns only those places within this radius, however how would I order them by distance so the closest is first? In the past, using raw SQL I have done the calculation within the SELECT statement and set it as 'distance' and then used `HAVING distance < $requestedDistance ORDER BY distance`, however I'm not sure how to add the calculation to the SELECT query using Doctrine Repository.

```
$d = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XXXWebsiteBundle:Locations')->createQueryBuilder('l');
        $d
            ->add('where','l.enabled = 1')
            ->andWhere('( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') )
                * cos( radians( l.latitude ) )
                * cos( radians( l.longitude )
                - radians('.$longitude.') )
                + sin( radians('.$latitude.') )
                * sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) < '.$requestedDistance);

       $result= $d->getQuery();
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried the following query thanks to @Lazy Ants:

```
$d = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XXXWebsiteBundle:Locations')->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $d
        ->select('l')
        ->addSelect(
            '( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . $latitude . '))' .
                '* cos( radians( l.latitude ) )' .
                '* cos( radians( l.longitude )' .
                '- radians(' . $longitude . ') )' .
                '+ sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') )' .
                '* sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
        )
        ->andWhere('l.enabled = :enabled')
        ->setParameter('enabled', 1)
        ->andWhere('distance < :distance')
        ->setParameter('distance', $requestedDistance)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT il0 FROM (SELECT l0_.id AS il0, l0_.name AS name2, l0_.address1 
AS address14, l0_.address2 AS address25, l0_.postcode AS postcode6, l0_.town AS 
town7, l0_.county AS county8, l0_.enabled AS enabled11, l0_.date_created AS 
date_created12, l0_.date_modified AS date_modified13, l0_.latitude AS 
latitude19, l0_.longitude AS longitude20, 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(53.51331889999999)) 
* COS(RADIANS(l0_.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(l0_.longitude) - 
RADIANS(-2.935331099999985)) + SIN(RADIANS(53.51331889999999)) * 
SIN(RADIANS(l0_.latitude))) AS sclr21 FROM locations l0_ WHERE l0_.enabled = ? 
AND sclr21 < ? ORDER BY sclr21 ASC) dctrn_result) dctrn_table' with params 
{"1":1,"2":30}:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr21' in 'where clause'`
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/djlambert/doctrine2-spatial

Comment: Answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272765/dql-returning-an-array-of-entities-instead-of-objects thanks to @Ocramius

Comment: This was a built in feature of Doctrine v1, so annoying they removed it. http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#geographical

Answer (score 5):

```
    $d = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XXXWebsiteBundle:Locations')->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $d
        ->select('l')
        ->addSelect(
            '( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . $latitude . '))' .
                '* cos( radians( l.latitude ) )' .
                '* cos( radians( l.longitude )' .
                '- radians(' . $longitude . ') )' .
                '+ sin( radians(' . $latitude . ') )' .
                '* sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
        )
        ->andWhere('l.enabled = :enabled')
        ->setParameter('enabled', 1)
        ->having('distance < :distance')
        ->setParameter('distance', $requestedDistance)
        ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
```

Comment: `An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT il0 FROM (SELECT *, 3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(53.51331889999999)) * COS(RADIANS(l0_.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(l0_.longitude) - RADIANS(-2.935331099999985)) + SIN(RADIANS(53.51331889999999)) * SIN(RADIANS(l0_.latitude))) AS sclr21 FROM locations l0_ WHERE l0_.enabled = ? AND sclr21 < ? ORDER BY sclr21 ASC) dctrn_result) dctrn_table' with params {"1":1,"2":30}:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr21' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I've removed some of the fields out of the error message because it was too long for a comment. I also changed `->andWhere('where', 'l.enabled = :enabled')` to `->andWhere('l.enabled = :enabled')` in your query

Comment: Also, would this return an array rather than objects?

Comment: Sorry for the late, here the right query:
remove:
        ->andWhere('distance < :distance')
and add:
->having('distance < :distance')
->setParameter('distance', $distance)

Comment: Is possible to use this Query in doctrine2? i don't see the acos function in Doctrine documentation. Is there any alternative?

Comment: yes, it's possible. you just need a custom function.
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/src/Query/Mysql
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using andWhere() without a where().

Replace the andWhere() with a where().

Please check also in your Entity definition if some property is mapped on a column called "sclr21", so you can discovery also on which property do you have the issue.