# Doctrine2 and where sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine query written like this:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb
        ->leftJoin('u.relatedEventTypes', 'relatedEventTypes')
        ->leftJoin('u.relatedGenres', 'relatedGenres')
        ->where(
            $qb->expr()->eq('u.type', ':userType')
        )
        ->setParameter('userType', 'dj')
    ;
```

I'd like to add one more where statement for finding distance between two coordiates and manipulating that data. Query looks like this:

```
    $qb
       ->andWhere(
          '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(lat_placeholder) ) * cos( radians(lat_placeholder) ) * cos( radians(lng_placeholder) - radians(lng_placeholder) ) +
           sin( radians(lat_placeholder) ) * sin( radians(la t_placeholder) ) ) ) AS distance
           HAVING distance < distanceToTravel_placeholder)'
     ;
```

I can't find a way to make this work meaning i can't figure out how to write this with placeholders so i can use variables from query from the begining(for example u.locLat, u.distanceToTravel etc.). Is it possible?

Comment: You should start with removing `LIMIT`, `ORDER BY` in a `andWhere` method.

Comment: I just used raw sql query, of course limit and order by statements don't belong there but i thought it would make my question more precise

Answer (score 1):

I think doctrine is not able to handle all the functions like acos, cos and radians. You should take a look at Doctrine [DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) or Doctrine [native queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) where DBAL looks like PDO and native queries offer you the possibility to fill entities with normal mysql queries.

Comment: It's plain sql in andWhere statement and sql supports all of these functions. Question is if it's possible to write it in doctrine with placeholders.

Comment: sql does support those functions but DQL doesn't

Comment: look for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267205/symfony2-doctrine-search-and-order-by-distance